# Kohana 3: set/get flash messages and sessions

Tags: session, kohana, kohana-3

My base controller has the following:

```
protected $session;

public function before()
{
    parent::before();

    $this->session = Session::instance();
}
```

I extend this controller and when the user is trying to login I redirect the user if username/password has not been filled in:

```
if($this->request->method() == Request::POST)
{
    $username = $this->request->post('username');
    $password = $this->request->post('password');

    if(strlen($username) == 0)
    {
        $this->session->set('error', 'Please enter a Username');
        Request::current()->redirect('user/login');
    }

    if(strlen($password) == 0)
    {
        $this->session->set('error', 'Please enter a Password');
        Request::current()->redirect('user/login');
    }
}

$error = $this->session->get_once('error');

$view = View::factory('user/login');
$view->bind('title', $title);
$view->bind('error', $error);
echo $view->render();
```

However the $error param is always NULL when it is returned. Is this because the session is getting reset via the Base controller? What should I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you complicate simple things so much? There is no need to use sessions for error handling...

```
if($this->request->method() == Request::POST)
{
    $username = $this->request->post('username');
    $password = $this->request->post('password');

    if(strlen($username) == 0)
    {
        $error = 'Please enter a Username';
    }

    if(strlen($password) == 0)
    {
        $error = 'Please enter a Password';
    }
}

$view = View::factory('user/login')
    ->bind('title', $title)
    ->bind('error', $error);
echo $view->render();
```

Comment: @martino thanks, although I would prefer to understand why the session variable is reset and if there is a workaround.

Comment: Try removing only the 2 redirects then and see what happens

Comment: thanks that worked. what would I need to change in order for the session value to remain if there was a redirect to a different controller?

Comment: The sessions/redirects are there to allow users to refresh the form after they unsuccessfully posted it without getting a form resubmit dialog.